# GWT FlexTable detect resize as Google Calendar

Tags: gwt, google-calendar-api, flextable

i've got a very simple calendar (3 weeks fixed). In every day i need one or more link. How can i simulate a Google Calendar view? 
I have mainly 2 problems when adding a link:

- i'm not able to fix column width (after an insert of a link as "ThisIsAVeryLongLinkInOnlyOneRow" my column is modified
- i'm not able to detect when an added event will overflow my cell (i'm not able to create the "N more" on Calendar).

I've tried many widget as gwt-scheduler or gwt-cal but they are too much for our need and we'd need to customize then too much.

Comment: for the first issuee add style property on table: "table-layout :fixed"; for the second you can schedule a timer and detect an overflow: content of cell bigger than width of the cell

Comment: later i'll trt table-layout. Probably i missed it! Regarding second point I've not explained me well. If i have a cell height of 120px and  i want adding a fixed-height list of element (ie 20 px) i can detect when i need the "N more" label (after 6 in this example), but what happens if the height is not fixed? For example if i want adding a 39,20,20,80 px height?